# Gitlab ci variables disappearing in pipeline run

Tags: gitlab, cicd

We have a large, fairly complex set of yaml files that defines pipeline configurations for multiple apps using gitlab ci.  A single pipeline consists of a dozen or more separate yaml configs that use `include` and `extends` directives.  In some cases we extend multiple sections and reference variables more than one layer deep of extends.  Here's an example:

First yaml file:

```
release-major:
  extends: .release-helm
  variables:
    RELEASE_TYPE: major
```

Second yaml file:

```
.release-helm:
  extends: .deploy-helm
  stage: release
  variables: !reference [.release-ref, variables, variables]
  rules:
    - !reference [.release-ref, rules]
  interruptible: true
  allow_failure: false

... more configs...

.release-ref:
  rules:
    - !reference [.base-job-ref, rules, disable-job]
    - !reference [.base-job-ref, rules, disable-stage]
    - !reference [.base-job-ref, rules, disable-on-trigger]
    - !reference [.base-job-ref, rules, disable-deploy-jobs]
    - !reference [.base-job-ref, rules, disable-release-job]
    - !reference [.base-job-ref, rules, disable-release-deploy-prod]
    - !reference [.base-job-ref, rules, deploy-branch-manual]
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: clone
    KUSTOMIZE_PATH: ${KUSTOMIZE_PRODUCTION_PATH}
    COSIGN_PASSWORD: ${COSIGN_PASSWORD_PROD}
    COSIGN_KEY_PATH: ${COSIGN_KEY_PATH_PROD}
    DEPLOYMENT_ENV: prod
    PROMOTE_FROM_TAG: staging
```

Third yaml file:

```
.deploy-helm:
  extends: .deploy
  script:
  # Does some git tagging
```

In the script, some of the variables defined in `.release-ref` are used.  However, in pipeline runs they do not exist.  I put debugging and `env` in the script and can clearly see they don't exist.

My understanding was that `variables` from multiple gitlab-ci files from `includes` and `extends` should merge together, and the highest level extension variable will take precedence in the event of the same variables existing.  However, this is clearly not the case.  I've tried moving the variables in `.release-ref` up the precedence chain even in the top level `release-major` variable block but they still disappear during the pipeline run.  What could be happening?